# Send data back to UITableViewController from UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have two different classes that both implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. They are separate from my `UITableViewController`.

I would like to choose the correct data source class to instantiate in `viewDidLoad()` and then set UITableViewController to be a delegate of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` classes.  (I return an object from these classes to UITableViewController for `prepareForSegue` to know what to display in the detail view controller screen.)

This doesn't work.

At runtime it breaks without a runtime error, just with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...) the line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {"

However, if I define the data source object as an instance variable in the UITableViewConroller (as opposed to doing it within `viewDidLoad()`) then it works. Of course, this defeats the purpose, since now I can't switch to another data source.

It seems that if I want to set UITableViewController as a delegate (i.e., want to be able to send data back from data source) then I can't do this in viewDidLoad() for some reason. Maybe it hasn't finished creating the objects yet? (Everything works if I create objects as instance variables and immediately initialise them.)

```
protocol GroupByDelegator {
    func callSegueFromGroupByDelegator()
}

class RemindersViewController: UITableViewController, GroupByDelegator {        
    @IBOutlet var remindersTableview: UITableView!

//    var dataSource = GroupByNothingDataSource()          // THIS WORKS, BUT THEN I CAN'T CHANGE THE DATASOURCE ANYMORE

    var reminderWrapperToBeDisplayedInDetailView: ReminderWrapper?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//  if ... {

        var dataSource = GroupByNothingDataSource()  // BREAKS THE CODE

//  } else {
//      var dataSource = GroupByPriorityDataSource()
//  }

        dataSource.groupByDelegator = self      // used so that the datasource can call the callSegueFromGroupByDelegator() func that will pass an object back to here.
        self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        self.tableView.delegate = dataSource
   }
...

    // This function is called by the data source delegates (GroupByNothingDataSource, GroupByPriorityDataSource) because they can't perform segues.
   func callSegueFromGroupByDelegator(reminderWrapper: ReminderWrapper?) {
    reminderWrapperToBeDisplayedInDetailView = reminderWrapper
    //try not to send self, just to avoid retain cycles
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("reminderDetail", sender: tableView)
    }

}



class GroupByPriorityDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, TableViewCellDelegate, RemindersViewControllerDelegate {    
    var groupByDelegator: GroupByDelegator!
    ...


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ...

    // Pass object back to UITableViewController
    self.groupByDelegator.callSegueFromGroupByDelegator(reminderWrapper?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up initializing both datasources as class instance variables (instead of initializing only one dynamically depending on the user interaction.) Now I choose between the already initialized datasources dynamically depending on the user interaction.

It solved my problem, but hasn't really addressed the technical issue. Is this a bug in the platform?